# SQL Query Select Line Number (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Do any of you know of a command or function that would produce the line number of the query window inside of select statement?  For example, if you are on line 34 it you would have select statement and the results would show 34. I am not looking to use row_number() function because we are not referencing a table.

Comment: Why would you care about the query editor line number in your SQL results? Are you trying to debug something?

Comment: Just wanted to know if it was possible? I've debated using a variable and just adding 1 to each statement of code.  Liking will have couple hundred lines of code with a bunch of sections and wanted a quick way to reference back to line numbers without having to use an incremental variable.

Comment: You can use a `PRINT 'blah'` statement. If you make 'blah' something unique for each instance, you have a quick way to jump to a section of code by using CTRL+F and searching for the unique text.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want without altering the stored procedure and adding `PRINT 'something'` statements.

While this tactic can be useful for quick-and-dirty stored procedure debugging, it does not beautify the code and, is not considered sustainable. There are better methods. Maybe look at a tutorial like this: https://www.sqlshack.com/debugging-stored-procedures-sql-server-management-studio-ssms/

Comment: And if you're not asking because you want to debug your SP, I am quite sure we don't understand your motives.